# how to stop reading "cat /dev/urandom"?

Tags: c, cat

i am writing a program that read the standard input.i have a loop like this :

```
while(read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
```

it works fine, but when i do a cat /dev/urandom | ./myprogram the loop never stop.So i would like to stop reading after some time elapsed.

Comment: I found it hard to stop reading Lord of the Rings. But /dev/urandom, though quote unpredictable, is too repetitive for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead, to get 2K of random data into `myprogram`:

```
  cat /dev/urandom | head -c 2000 | ./myprogram
```

Comment: well actually i want to avoid that, because i just want to prevent reading from very large file.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to set an alarm using `alarm()`.

```
alarm(1);

{
  size_t ssizeReadTotal = 0;

  {
    ssize_t ssizeRead = 0;

    while (0 < (ssizeRead = read(0, buffer + sizeReadTotal, sizeof(buffer) - sizeReadTotal)))
    {
      sizeReadTotal += ssizeRead;
    }

    if (0 > ssizeRead) 
    {
      if (EINTR == errno))
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Filling the buffer was interrupted by alarm clock.\n");

      }
      else /* some *real* error occurred */
      {
        perror("read()");
      }
    }
  }

  if (sizeof(buffer) > sizeReadTotal)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "The buffer was not fully initialised!\n");
  }
}
```

This signals `SIGALRM` after one second. The signal interupts the call to `read()`. It will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Also the `read()`ing stops when the buffer had been filled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this not long ago. You could use `time` and `difftime`, for example like this:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
double max_seconds = 1.0;
while (read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0 && difftime(time(NULL), t) < max_seconds) {
    /* ... */
}
```